# TYPO3 - Extbase Custom query w/ QueryBuilder: How to add action show to url for links to work again

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x

When run I this query ... there is no show action in the links in my list view ... and they do not work anymore:

Controller.php

```
$uid = 10;
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tt_content');
$statement = $queryBuilder  
    ->select('uid', 'pid', 'header')            
    ->from('tt_content')
    ->where(
       $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uid', $uid)
    )           
    ->execute();    
while ($row = $statement->fetchAll()) {
    $this->view->assign('inet', $row);
}
```

Console:

```
<tr id="2">
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="name"><a href="code/?tx_code_code%5Brecord%5D%5Buid%5D=2&amp;tx_code_code%5Brecord%5D%5Bcode%5D=25490004X&amp;tx_code_code%5Brecord%5D%5Bname%5D=Company%20Name%20Inc&amp;cHash=e8e3573028618746234">Company Name Inc</a></td>
</tr>
```

When I debug it I can see that I render the following array:

```
array(20 items)
   0 => array(3 items)
      uid => 1 (integer)
      code => '213800' (6 chars)
      name => 'Company Name Inc' (16 chars)
```

How can I get the links to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<f:link.action action="show" pageUid="43" arguments="{record:record}">{record.name}</f:link.action>
```

to

```
<f:link.action action="show" pageUid="43" arguments="{record:record.uid}">{record.name}</f:link.action>
```

because you ain't getting Objects anymore but arrays of database rows.
Additionally your listAction is missing the parameters $minUid and $maxUid.

Comment: Great ... that helped!